# Python regex fuzzy searching

Tags: python, regex

I have a question about making a pattern using fuzzy regex with the python `regex` module.

I have several strings such as TCATGCACGTGGGGCTGAC

The first eight characters of this string are variable (multiple options): TCAGTGTG, TCATGCAC, TGGTGGCT. In addition, there is a constant part after the variable part: GTGGGGCTGAC.

I would like to design a regex that can detect this string in a longer string, while allowing for at most 2 substitutions.

For example, this would be acceptable as two characters have been substituted:

TCATGCACGTGGGGCTGAC
TC**C**TGCACGTGG**A**GCTGAC

However, more substitutions should not be accepted.

In my code, I tried to do the following:

```
import regex

variable_parts = ["TCAGTGTG", "TCATGCAC", "TGGTGGCT", "GATAAGTG", "ATTAGACG", "CACTTCCG", "GTCTGTAT", "TGTCAAAG"]
string_to_test = "TCATGCACGTGGGGCTGAC"
motif = "(%s)GTGGGGCTGAC" % "|".join(variable_parts)
pattern = regex.compile(r''+motif+'{s<=2}')

print(pattern.search(string_to_test))
```

I get a match when I run this code and when I change the last character of `string_to_test`. But when I manually add a substitution in the middle of `string_to_test`, I do not get any match (even while I want to allow up to 2 substitutions).

Now I know that my regex is probably total crap, but I would like to know what I exactly need to do to make this work and where in the code I need to add/remove/change stuff. Any suggestions/tips are welcome!

Comment: Which part do you allow to be different? Right now, you only add the restriction to the last `C` in the pattern. It looks like `(TCAGTGTG|TCATGCAC|TGGTGGCT|GATAAGTG|ATTAGACG|CACTTCCG|GTCTGTAT|TGTCAAAG)GTGGGGCTGAC{s<=2}`. Did you mean to write `regex.compile(r'(?:'+motif+'){s<=2}')`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `biopython` for this? It seems like you might be able to avoid creating your own solution

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like to entire pattern have at most 2 substitutions. So not only the C, but also the rest of the motif

Comment: So, `regex.compile(r'(?:'+motif+'){s<=2}')`?

Comment: @Andrew there is no particular reason, I was just curious. Is there an interesting Biopython module that is good for me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you only add the restriction to the last `C` in the pattern that looks likelooks like `(TCAGTGTG|TCATGCAC|TGGTGGCT|GATAAGTG|ATTAGACG|CACTTCCG|GTCTGTAT|TGTCAAAG)GTGGGGCTGAC{s<=2}`.

To apply the `{s<=2}` quantifier to the *whole* expression you need to enclose the pattern within a non-capturing group:

```py
pattern = regex.compile(fr'(?:{motif}){{s<=2}}')
```

The example above shows how to declare your pattern with the help of an f-string literal, where literal braces are defined with `{{` and `}}` (doubled) braces. It yields the same result as `pattern = regex.compile('(?:'+motif+'){s<=2}')`.

Also, note that `r''+` is redundant and has no effect on the final pattern.